# SQL Lite Average Score

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

```
PreStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(""
                        + "SELECT Game1.AVG(Score),Students.FirstName,Students.LastName "
                        + "FROM Game1 " 
                        + "INNER JOIN Students " 
                        + "ON Game1.StudentID = Students.StudentID " 
                        + "ORDER BY Students.FirstName ASC;");
```

This doesent work.  (The error is definatly the AVG Score part)
But this does.

```
PreStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(""
                        + "SELECT AVG(Score),
                        + "FROM Game1 "
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I going to have o make two statements to get my average scores.

Comment: "This doesent work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
PreStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(""
                        + "SELECT AVG(Game1.Score),Students.FirstName,Students.LastName "
                        + "FROM Game1 " 
                        + "INNER JOIN Students " 
                        + "ON Game1.StudentID = Students.StudentID " 
                        + "ORDER BY Students.FirstName ASC;");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the average per student, then you should be using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT AVG(g.Score), s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Game1 g INNER JOIN
     Students s
     ON g.StudentID = s.StudentID 
GROUP BY s.FirstName, s.LastName
ORDER BY s.FirstName ASC;
```

Table aliases also make the query easier to write and to read.